# Random Red Border Around Input Elements

Tags: jquery, html, onchange

Does anyone know what the red border that sometimes gets put around `input` elements on webpages is? Is it from HTML5 or jQuery? I have seen it when I am using `required` as an attribute and also when I use jQuery's `change` function (as well as `on("change")`, obviously). At first I thought it was when you don't have the right `pattern` in an `input` field on form submit, but recently I found it happening with this code:

```
<form id="assessform" action="assessment.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="assessform">

    <div data-test-ques="met_with">

        <label data-test-num="met_with" for="met_with">Met With </label>

        <input type="text" name="met_with" id="met_with" value="" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />

    </div><br /><br />

    <div data-test-ques="taken_by">

        <label data-test-num="taken_by" for="taken_by">Assessment Taken By </label>

        <input type="text" name="taken_by" id="taken_by" value="" required="required" />

    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#met_with, #taken_by").change(function() {
    if($("#met_with").val() == met_with || $("#taken_by").val() == taken_by) {
        met_taken_change = 0;
    }
    else {
        met_taken_change = 1;
    }
});
```

I get the `required` thing, but why here?

Screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle please

Comment: I can -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6aAK/)........ and what red border, I don't think I've ever seen anything like that in Chrome, so what browser are you using, and what does it look like? This is one of the times where a picture would be great !

Comment: Firefox. Will add a screenshot to my post.

Comment: I think I know what happened. The behavior is caused by `required`, not jQuery. For some reason, when you change an input field with `required="required"`, then `tab` to the next field, then change it back, it makes a red border but when you leave it blank, then `tab` to the next field, nothing happens. Very strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a random behavior, it's just a different implementation of the html5 spec in FF for the 'required' input attr.

FF adds a red border to help us focus on the problem, you can see it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required).

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was from `onchange` because of the way my site did it. It's confusing, though, they could have made it better. Of course, since I couldn't make it better myself I shouldn't be talking.